# amCharts cropping all the bullets, when all the values are zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

I am using `xy/bubble` chart from `amChart` plugin. I have used `minmaxmultiplier` property for adding extra space at top/bottom, so that the Bullets should not get cropped.
But when all the values are zero, the bullets get cropped from bottom.

Below is the sample for the same.
[Code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLJMVN)

Comment: `minMaxMultiplier` generally works but there might be a bug for this particular instance. I'll report this to the devs but I recommend manually setting your vertical value axis minimum and maximum for now to account for the spacing. You might also want to set `showFirstLabel` false if you don't want to display the first label (such hiding -1 if you use `minimum: -1`)

Comment: @xorspark i have solved it by manually setting the min values and also thanks for the suggestion of `showFirstLabel`, which also solved my other problem of hiding negative axis.